# second GPU not identified in PCIe x4

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have 2 GPUs for machine learning, an old GTX Titan and a newer GTX 1080 ti. My board is an Gigabyte Z370M which have 2 PCIe x16 and x4.
The situation is both GPUs are detected by lshw in x16 slot. But only the 1080 ti is detected in the x4 slot. Of course, it makes more sense to use the 1080 ti in the x16.
I've found a post in a forum where the same situation was described but OS was Windows, the problem was solved updating chipset driver.
I raised this question to the Gigabyte support, their recomendation was to install Windows... very bad.
Considering that both GPUs are working and both PCIe slots are also working, I imagine this is not imposible to be solved.
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, up to date. BIOS version is F13 from November 2019.
I think the Nvidia driver version is not relevant here since the GPU is not identified by Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for the help.
Felipe

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is your BIOS up to date with the latest firmware? You said that the Titan works in the x16 slot and the 1080ti works in the x4 slot. Any reason not to just use them in that configuration? Also, may be good to edit the question with what drivers you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  I've edited the post accordingly. My BIOS is up to date. About using the 1080 ti in x4 slot,  the problem is the newer GPU is about 4x faster than the old one,  therefore if I use it in x4 I will lose overall performance.